# app crashses after update but not after re-install

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-play, ionic-native

I've uploaded a new beta version of my app to the Google Play store.

If I update to the new version from an existing version, the app crashes right after the splash screen.

BUT, if I uninstall and re-install the new version, the app works fine.

Any idea what can cause this scenario? any idea how can I understand what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Have your tried connecting to adb logcat to see what the console output is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check logcat for crashing reasons, were to an application crash.
Possible reason is :
**You access the data in the new version of the application, which is not available in the old version of the application.**

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that I added properties to my data classes, but I didn't add migration to the room DB, so I received exceptions when building the room DB.

I don't fully understand why it caused me exceptions only when updating the app to the new version, and not when uninstalling the older version and then installing the new one. I can see some logic in it, but I would love to hear (or read...) an exact explanation if anyone knows.

Thanks.